# App Pool Timeout Destroys ASP.NET code behind properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis, asp.net-ajax

I am maintaining some data in form of a dictionary as an ASP.NET code behind property. When the App Pool timeout is reached, dictionary with data is destroyed (surprisingly other string properties are not).

I am using PageMethods (works like AJAX) to load part of the data from my dictionary as per the request by Javascript.

I need to detect when the App Pool has timed out in my code behind, so that I could probably refresh the page.

Dictionary is being stored in an object wrapper as:

> public partial class SourceWorkqueue : System.Web.UI.Page
>   {
>   internal static ObjectType _dbList;

Comment: How is your dictionary being stored?  In a Session variable?  In an Application variable?  In a variable on the page?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: So let me understand your problem.  You have an aspx page that a user is looking at.  Then, the app pool times out while they are looking at the page and some or all of information in the code behind gets destroyed?  If the app pool is timing out so fast then you should increase it.If the user is sitting on the page for hours without doing anything then that's a different issue.

Comment: I can increase the timeout but that's not a preferred solution. Would there be any way I could determine in the code behind that the app pool has timed out? Or that my information in code behind has been destroyed by the app pool?

Comment: Why don't you simply check if _dbList is null and if it is then repopulate it?